# how to find the value(s) of k that makes the vectors $(2,-1,4), (2,k+6,k)$, and $(1,0,2)$ linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

my approach to the problem was to build an arbitrary vector $(a,b,c)$ representing the span of $v_1$ and $v_3$ i.e $((2,-1,4) , (1,0,2))$ in terms of their coefficients($c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively) :

$c_1(2,-1,4) + c_2(1,0,2) = (a,b,c) => (2c_1 +c_2 , -c_1 , 4c_1+2c_2)$ I noticed that the $c$ in my arbitrary vector is nothing but $2a$. 
now solving for the problem i find that $k=4$ so the answer would be any value of $k$ other than $4$.

is this the right answer and is there another way to solve for this problem?

Comment: You could look at the determinant formed and ensure it is nonzero. You'll get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2,k+6,k)=a(2,-1,4)+b(1,0,2)$$
$$
\begin{align}
&2a+b=2\\
&k+6=-a\\
&k=4a+2b=2(2a+b)=4\\
&\therefore k=4\quad(a=-5,\space b=12)
\end{align}
$$